# Node gyp not working (WindowsError: [Error 183] ═хтючьюцэю ёючфрЄ№ Їрщы,)

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

1. I tried to uninstall node/npm, installing LTS and Latest.
2. I tried windows-build-tools
3. I installed Visual Studio 2017 and Python 2.7 manually

Nothing helped, during installation of native plugin node-gyp exit with following error:

```
npm i

v8-profiler@5.7.0 preinstall C:\VRNET\VRnet\viewers\web\node_modules\v8-profiler
> node -e 'process.exit(0)'


v8-profiler@5.7.0 install C:\VRNET\VRnet\viewers\web\node_modules\v8-profiler
node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://node-inspector.s3.amazonaws.com/profiler/v5.7.0/node-v64-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for v8-profiler@5.7.0 and node@10.15.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://node-inspector.s3.amazonaws.com/profiler/v5.7.0/node-v64-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for v8-profiler@5.7.0 and node@10.15.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in 
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 523, in gyp_main
    generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 2025, in GenerateOutput
    version=msvs_version)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSNew.py", line 213, in __init__
    self.Write()
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSNew.py", line 340, in Write
    f.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\common.py", line 393, in close
    os.rename(self.tmp_path, filename)
WindowsError: [Error 183] ═хтючьюцэю ёючфрЄ№ Їрщы,
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\VRNET\\VRnet\\viewers\\web\\node_modules\\v8-profiler\\build\\profiler\\v5.7.0\\node-v64-win32-x64\\profiler.node" "--module_name=profiler" "--module_path=C:\\VRNET\\VRnet\\viewers\\web\\node_modules\\v8-profiler\\build\\profiler\\v5.7.0\\node-v64-win32-x64" "--python=C:\\Program Files\\Python27\\python.exe"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\VRNET\VRnet\viewers\web\node_modules\v8-profiler
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\VRNET\VRnet\viewers\web\node_modules\v8-profiler\build\profiler\v5.7.0\node-v64-win32-x64\profiler.node --module_name=profiler --module_path=C:\VRNET\VRnet\viewers\web\node_modules\v8-profiler\build\profiler\v5.7.0\node-v64-win32-x64 --python=C:\Program Files\Python27\python.exe' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\VRNET\VRnet\viewers\web\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\VRNET\\VRnet\\viewers\\web\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\VRNET\VRnet\viewers\web\node_modules\v8-profiler
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\VRNET\VRnet\viewers\web\node_modules\v8-profiler\build\profiler\v5.7.0\node-v64-win32-x64\profiler.node --module_name=profiler --module_path=C:\VRNET\VRnet\viewers\web\node_modules\v8-profiler\build\profiler\v5.7.0\node-v64-win32-x64 --python=C:\Program Files\Python27\python.exe' (1)
npm WARN vrnet@ No repository field.
npm WARN vrnet@ No license field.
npm WARN The package gulp-uglify is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package pump is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package serve-static is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package webdav-server is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: v8-profiler@5.7.0 (node_modules\v8-profiler):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: v8-profiler@5.7.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

audited 9137 packages in 17.225s
found 167 vulnerabilities (148 low, 10 moderate, 9 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Where can be the problem - how to make gyp working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it does not work properly whatever I do with installed Visual Studio, I removed it, install build-tools with npm and now all works.